# Consuming Kafka Topic from dotnet core is going to infinite loop

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, apache-kafka

Consuming Kafka Topic from dotnet core is going to infinite loop.

```
consumer.Subscribe("my topic name");
 while (true){ var kfReslt = consumer.Consume() }
```

Comment: You are calling `Consume` in an infinite loop so when would you expect the loop to exit?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expected. You've written `while(true)`... If you look at the documentation, there's a continuation token that should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `CancellationToken` to stop consuming.

Here is an example of a console app that consumes the Kafka topic on a background thread:

```
using CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Task task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    consumer.Subscribe("my topic name");
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var kfReslt = consumer.Consume();
        //...
    }
});

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop consuming...");
Console.ReadKey();
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```